# Nested resource being destroyed but associated model should prevent this (validation in Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes

I have a `TimeWorked` class with a `has_one`(one or zero) relation with `Event`

The `Event` is manipulated in my controller as a nested_resource of `TimeWorked`, and works fine for create and update.

I put validation on my `TimeWorked`so that I prevent modification (update or destroy) when the object is signed (final).

I followed all the updated answers(as Rails 5 changed the way `chain_halted` works) I could find here on SO.

So far I can prevent my main model `TimeWorked` from being destroyed or updated, but even with the `throw(:abort)` ActiveRecord is still destroying my associated resource `TimeWorkedEvent` with it.

How can I prevent this model AND it's nested resource from being destroyed ?

Models (`TimeWorked`/`Event`/`Join table`):

```
class TimeWorked < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :time_worked_event, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :event, through: :time_worked_event
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :time_worked_event, reject_if: proc {|att| att[:event_id].blank?}

  # cannot destroy timeworked that has been signed
  before_destroy do
     not_signed
     throw(:abort) if errors.present?
  end

 def not_signed
    errors.add(:signed, "Cannot modify or destroy a signed timeworked") if signed_exist?
  end

end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
end

class TimeWorkedEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :time_worked
  validates_presence_of :event
  validates_presence_of :time_worked
  validates_uniqueness_of :time_worked_id
end
```

Controller:

```
class TimeWorkedController < ApplicationController
 def destroy
    @time_worked.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: The documentation should be approached first to find some help. Rails official [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) **clearly** demonstrates the use-case along with the solution which is shared in the accepted answer. Please look for *Ordering callbacks* section. Doing that should also give one an opportunity to appreciate the documentation authors!

Comment: well before the accepted answer and it's explanation I had no idea it had something to do with callback ordering, but rather something linked to validation and nested resource, which I'm still new with.
thanks for the resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because before_destroy runs after dependent: destroy callback. So you can do something like this for calling it before dependent: destroy -

```
  before_destroy :check, prepend: true

  def check
    not_signed
    throw(:abort) if errors.present?
  end
```

Comment: exactly what I needed, thanks a lot !
That's why i love & hate rails at the same time , one keyword and all your problems appear/disappear